# Cross compile Snort with OpenApp ID enabled

Tags: cross-compiling, autotools, libtool, snort

I am trying to build Snort 2.9.9.0 for an ARM device using uClibc and the openwrt toolchain.

I am constantly having compilation issues including:

• `libtool attempting to link library **/usr/lib/libdnet** rather than $TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/lib/libdnet`

I suspect my problems are stemming from autotools, because all the required libraries are in place and my configure script runs after modifications to prevent cross compilation errors ('Cannot configure while cross compiling').

My question is:

1. What is the correct method of using autotools for cross compilation
   in this snort cross compilation context?
2. The configure script attempts to
   execute compiled programs and throws an error for cross compilation,
   how can I supply a cached answer to it's compilation testing rather than modify the configure script?
3. How should my build script look for sucessfully cross compiling
   snort-2.9.9.0 with openapp-id enabled on my x84_64 for an ARM device
   target.

I do not know much about autotools, any information regarding autotools and cross compialtion would be appreciated.

My build script is the following:

```
••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••• 
#!/bin/bash

./configure
--target=arm-openwrt-linux-uclibceabi \
--host=arm-openwrt-linux-uclibceabi \
--build=x86_64-linux \
--prefix=/usr \
--enable-flexresp \
--with-libpcap-includes=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/include \
--with-libpcap-libraries=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/lib \
--with-libpcre-includes=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/include \
--with-libpcre-libraries=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/lib \
--with-daq-includes=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/include \
--with-daq-libraries=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/lib \
--disable-static-daq \
--enable-open-appid \
--disable-lzma \
CPPFLAGS=" \
-I$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/include \
-I$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/include \
-I/home/antony/gwn/system/opensource/user/snort-2.9.9.0/librpc_ipq8064/include \
-I$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/include/luajit-2.0 \
" \
LDFLAGS=" \
-L$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/usr/lib \
-L$TOOLCHAIN_DIR/librpc/lib \
"

make clean

make

DESTDIR=$TOOLCHAIN_DIR make install
•••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

If relevant, here are my environmental variables:

`CROSS_PREFIX=arm-openwrt-linux-`

`SHELL=/bin/bash`

`KERNEL_PATH=/home/antony/MY_SDK/kernel/ipq8064/linux-3.4.103/`

`TOOLCHAIN_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi//include/`

`LDCFLAGS=/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi//usr/lib/`

`USER=antony`

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi//usr/lib/`

`MKIMAGE_PATH=/home/antony/MY_SDK/tools/bin`

`PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/`

`LZMA_PATH=/home/antony/MY_SDK/tools/bin/`

`PATH=/home/antony/bin:/home/antony/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/bin`

`LD=arm-openwrt-linux-ld`

`PWD=/home/antony/MY_SDK/user/snort-2.9.9.0`

`STRIP=arm-openwrt-linux-strip`

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

`PROV_PATH=/home/antony/MY_SDK/system/provision/provision.h`

`IMAGE_BUILD=/home/antony/MY_SDK//image_build/`

`HOME=/home/antony`

`SHLVL=2`

`TOOLCHAIN_BASE_DIR=/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/`

`STAGING_DIR=/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/`

`LOGNAME=antony`

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/antony/MY_SDK/OpenWrt-Toolchain-arm_v7-a-gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi/toolchain-arm_v7-a_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2_eabi//usr/lib/pkgconfig`

`LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s`

`PROJECT_BASE_DIR=/home/antony/MY_SDK/`

`CC=arm-openwrt-linux-gcc`

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What is the correct method of using autotools for cross compilation in this snort cross compilation context?

Given a `configure` script built with Autoconf 2.50 or later (latest is v2.69), the correct way to enter cross-compilation mode is to run it with `--build` and `--host` options specifying differing system types.  The `--target` option is irrelevant for this purpose, and in fact applies mainly to configuring software that builds code.  You should not need it.

> 2. The configure script attempts to execute compiled programs and throws an error for cross compilation, how can I supply a cached
>      answer to it's compilation testing rather than modify the configure
>      script?

If the `configure` script performs tests that involve executing programs built with the selected toolchain, then either it is not running in cross compilation mode or those tests are explicitly programmed into `configure`.  The wrapper script you presented ought to put `configure` into cross compilation mode, so I'm guessing the latter.  In that case, you're probably looking at modifying the `configure` script to fix the problem.  (Or, actually, modifying its M4 source in `configure.ac` and rebuilding it.)

> 3. How should my build script look for sucessfully cross compiling snort-2.9.9.0 with openapp-id enabled on my x84_64 for an ARM device
>      target.

That depends a lot on the `configure` script.  I wouldn't have expected you to need to specify a bunch of `$TOOLCHAIN`-relative directory names to it, though those related to specific libraries are more plausible than those designating directories that the cross-compilation toolchain ought to be using anyway.  Although I cannot evaluate the details, I don't see any red flags in the `configure` invocation in your wrapper script.